# Proper way to implement array and selection store

Tags: angular, ngrx

### Context

I have a basic application, which gets data from a realtime database (firestore) and displays it to the user to let him interact with it.

The base model of everything is called `List`, users can create them, delete them, get their lists and the public ones.

I have firestore queries implemented for each of the cases (because getting all the lists of the app and then filtering is obviously a bad choice).

### Problem

I don't know how to properly handle state with these 3 type of data, because I need to store the lists created by the user, public lists and then I need to have a view where you can see details of a list and interact with it (which is basically a set of updates done by the user).

The issue is that if I implement a basic store, it will manage `List[]` and then I'll use `Array.find()` to get the desired list based on its id (random string). This feels really bad and I'm sure there's a better way to handle such a thing.

As every tutorial application I've seen are either too complex (ngrx/example-app is too complex for a beginner) or they don't talk about this case, I don't know where to go.

### Current state

Everything is pretty simple and can be seen on the github repo of the application:

https://github.com/Supamiu/ffxiv-teamcraft/tree/ngrx/src/app/core/ngrx/list

Current reducer:

```
// Define state
export interface ListsState {
    loading: boolean; // indicates loading while fetching data
    lists: List[];
}

// Define initial state
const initialState: ListsState = {
    loading: false,
    lists: []
};

// reducer function
export function listReducer(state = initialState,
                            action: ListActions.All): ListsState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ListActions.FETCH_USER_LISTS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        }
        case ListActions.FETCH_USER_LISTS_SUCCESS: {
            return {
                lists: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
        }
        case ListActions.DELETE_LIST: {
            state.lists = state.lists.filter(l => l.$key !== action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false
            }
        }
        case ListActions.ADD_LIST: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        }
        case ListActions.ADD_LIST_SUCCESS: {
            state.lists.push(action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false
            }
        }
        case SAVE_LIST: {
            const listIndex = state.lists.map(list => list.$key).indexOf(action.payload.$key);
            state.lists[listIndex] = action.payload;
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false
            }
        }
        default: {
            return state
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer, what exactly do you think is bad approach? getting in store by id? but it's always like that when you work with arrays in the store.

Alternative could be to use not arrays but dictionaries, but basically it would be the same, but just different manipulation... 

The bad thing, that is not supposed to be done is that you can't mutate the state, you need to create a new array each time you add/delete/update

`like state.lists.map((l) => l.$key === key ? someUpdate() : l);`

Comment: What I feel bad is that the app will only manage an array of lists, what if I delete a list that is currently seen by the user? You mean that I should change the implementation of the array behind my state? like creating a new one each time to ensure immutable state?

Comment: Right!

Regarding list removing, I think you are the king of your state, so for example you can create extra state property called `currentList` -> and in reducer pass `null` in case it's removed, and subscribe on changes in the component that need currentList and close/navigate back it when it's not available.